# The /MT option (static link for MSVCR100.dll dependency) does not work with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I am using a DLL that I compile with MSVC9 (Visual Studio 10 C++).
There is a dependency on msvcp100d.dll and msvcr100d.dll.

I would to make a static link in order to use my DLL standalone . To do so I use /MT instead of /MD option in my makefile.

Howewer when I check with dumpbin or dependency walker the dependency are still present, the msvcp100d.dll and msvcr100d.dll seems to be still dynamically linked.

Another thing that seems to be related, if I use the DLL through VS I have no problem, If I use another program I have a crash - it seems to be releated !

Thanks !

Comment: You did not compile *all* the code that gets linked into the DLL with /MT.  Forgetting to rebuild libraries is the standard mistake.  Using /MT with DLL projects is a very, very, very bad idea.  That crash is normal.   /MT was meant for very simple single-executable projects that you want to deploy by just copying a single file.  No point to it whatsoever when you have to copy multiple files anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have the crash when I compile with /MD. You are telling me that this will be a better solution to compile with MD and deliver the dependencies too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Hans Passant he was right, I was linking using another DLL where the dependencies msvcp100d.dll and msvcr100d.dll present.
So even with a static compilation of my DLL I still need the others DLL. 
I'll deliver with these DLL in release mode.